# Is it possible to use a cast operation for update expression in MongoDB C# drivers?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

I have this simple hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Foo 
{
    
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}

public class Container
{
    public Foo? Foo { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to do the update like that:

```
Builders<Container>.Update.Set(x => ((Bar) x.Foo!).Value, true);
```

The update fails though:

> MongoDB.Driver.Linq.ExpressionNotSupportedException: Expression not supported: Convert(x.Foo, Bar).

I have a similar expression for projection and that one works with convert. I am not trying to do some conversion in the database here, but just to set in the expression to update one given field in a polymorphic object.

P.S. `as` fails with a similar error

Comment: Is an update without a lambda expression like `Builders<Container>.Update.Set("Foo.Value", true);` an option?

Comment: Yes, that is what I had reverted to, so yes, this is definitely an option. I would like to avoid that though to rely more on C# static checking (like projections or filters). If I write it myself, I am on my own (for better or worse). But maybe it is really not a big deal and I should just do it.

Comment: Still only a work-around, but `$"{nameof(Foo)}.{nameof(Bar.Value)}"` adds type-safety, but is not easy to read also. In addition, property names in the document must match the names in code.

Comment: Yes, I actually did exactly this :) But as you say it is not exactly easy to read.